# No info manual for Pinfo

Tags: mac-osx

I have had a problem with Pinfo's search in reading manuals.
I believe that the following error message contains the suggestion to the solution.

I get the following error message

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/pinfo_error.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/pinfo_error.png)

The same in text:

> przemek's info viewer v0.6.9" error:
>   could not open info file, trying
>   manual

I have found unrelated links about the topic.
They suggested that the problem may be in my INFOPATH:

```
/sw/share/info:/sw/info:/usr/share/info
```

The main problem is not [in MacPorts](http://209.85.129.132/search?q=cache:3ir0iiWXWu4J:markmail.org/message/45wu2kboc46nkzp7+%22przemek%27s+info+viewer%22+error:+could+not+open+info+file,+trying+manual&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=fi&lr=lang_en). Thanks to dlamblin!

If you know answer to the problem, please, add it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular **`info find`** will end up doing the same thing. Mac OS X doesn't seem to come with an info file on **`find`**. Did you install a MacPorts version of **`find`** that came with an info file? Try **`pinfo info`**, I know I have that page in `/usr/share/info` (which is searched despite my not having an `$INFOPATH` set).

Comment: I get the following warning when I try to see whether I installed pinfo with an info file. --- I know that I did not put any option like +man when I installed pinfo.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the error message occurs irregularly or I managed to fix the problem by putting the following [.pinforc](http://os.cqu.edu.au/cgi-bin/info/info2html.cgi?%28pinfo%29Example%20config%20file) to my HOME:

```
  #
  # Here are some colour setting.
  # Whitespace between the entries is optional.
  #
  COL_NORMAL        =COLOR_WHITE,    COLOR_BLACK, NO_BOLD, NO_BLINK
  COL_MENUSELECTED  =COLOR_RED,      COLOR_BLACK, BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_MENU          =COLOR_BLUE,     COLOR_BLACK, BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_NOTESELECTED  =COLOR_RED,      COLOR_BLACK, BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_NOTE          =COLOR_GREEN,    COLOR_BLACK, BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_TOPLINE       =COLOR_YELLOW,   COLOR_BLUE,  BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_BOTTOMLINE    =COLOR_YELLOW,   COLOR_BLUE,  BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_MANUALBOLD    =COLOR_WHITE,    COLOR_BLACK, BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_MANUALITALIC  =COLOR_WHITE,    COLOR_BLACK, BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_URL           =COLOR_MAGENTA,  COLOR_BLACK, BOLD,    NO_BLINK
  COL_URLSELECTED   =COLOR_RED,      COLOR_BLACK, NO_BOLD, NO_BLINK
  COL_INFOHIGHLIGHT =COLOR_WHITE,    COLOR_BLACK, BOLD,    NO_BLINK

  #
  # Here are some keybindings as well...
  #
  KEY_TOTALSEARCH_1    ='s'
  KEY_TOTALSEARCH_2    ='S'
  KEY_SEARCH_1         ='/'
  KEY_SEARCH_2         ='.'
  KEY_GOTO_1           ='g'
  KEY_GOTO_2           ='m'
  KEY_HOME_1           ='h'
  KEY_HOME_2           ='H'
  KEY_PREVNODE_1       ='p'
  KEY_PREVNODE_2       ='P'
  KEY_NEXTNODE_1       ='n'
  KEY_NEXTNODE_2       ='N'
  KEY_UP_1             =KEY_UP
  KEY_UP_2             ='u'
  KEY_END_1            =KEY_END
  KEY_END_2            ='e'
  KEY_PGDN_1           =KEY_NPAGE
  KEY_PGDN_2           =' '
  KEY_PGDN_AUTO_1      =0
  KEY_PGDN_AUTO_2      =' '
  KEY_PGUP_1           =KEY_PPAGE
  KEY_PGUP_2           ='b'
  KEY_PGUP_AUTO_1      =0
  KEY_PGUP_AUTO_2      ='b'
  KEY_DOWN_1           =KEY_DOWN
  KEY_DOWN_2           ='d'
  KEY_TOP_1            =KEY_HOME
  KEY_TOP_2            ='t'
  KEY_BACK_1           =KEY_LEFT
  KEY_BACK_2           ='l'
  KEY_FOLLOWLINK_1     =KEY_RIGHT
  KEY_FOLLOWLINK_2     ='\n'
  # 12 is a code for ctrl+l
  KEY_REFRESH_1        =KEY_CTRL('l')
  KEY_REFRESH_2        ='~'
  KEY_SHELLFEED_1      ='!'
  KEY_SHELLFEED_2      ='1'
  KEY_QUIT_1           ='q'
  KEY_QUIT_2           ='Q'
  KEY_DIRPAGE_1        ='d'
  KEY_DIRPAGE_2        ='D'
  KEY_GOLINE_1         ='l'
  KEY_GOLINE_2         =0
  KEY_PRINT_1          =']'
  KEY_PRINT_2          =0
  KEY_SEARCH_AGAIN_1   ='f'
  KEY_SEARCH_AGAIN_2   =0

  #
  # Some options, explained in the man page
  #
  MANUAL=false
  CUT-MAN-HEADERS=true
  CUT-EMPTY-MAN-LINES=true
  RAW-FILENAME=false
  APROPOS=false
  DONT-HANDLE-WITHOUT-TAG-TABLE=false
  LONG-MANUAL-LINKS=false
  FILTER-0xB7=true
  QUIT-CONFIRMATION=false
  QUIT-CONFIRM-DEFAULT=no
  CLEAR-SCREEN-AT-EXIT=true
  STDERR-REDIRECTION="2> /dev/null"
  HTTPVIEWER=lynx
  FTPVIEWER=lynx
  MAILEDITOR=pine
  MANLINKS=1:8:2:3:4:5:6:7:9:n:p:o:3X11:3Xt
  INFOPATH=/usr/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/local/info
  HIGHLIGHTREGEXP=bash.*has
  SAFE-USER=nobody
  SAFE-GROUP=nobody
```